# Compare a string with column values in a table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a column in a database that contains emails. I have a method that takes an email as parameter, and I want to compare this given parameter with all the emails in the database, to see if it exits.
Normally I would do something like this, given that the emails were in some list

```
internal bool EmailAlreadyExists(string email)
    {
        foreach(var currentEmail in someList) 
        {
          if(currentEmail.Equals(email) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
internal bool EmailAlreadyExists(string email)
    {
        _msqlCon.Open();
        _query = "SELECT email FROM RegisteredUsers";
        _command = new MySqlCommand(_query, _msqlCon);

        foreach(var currentEmail in ???)
    }
```

How can I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DataReader to read values from the database.

```
var list = new List<string>();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dataReader.Read())
{
    list.Add(dataReader["email"].ToString());
}

dataReader.Close();
```

You could check the existence of the email directly in the database

```
_query = "SELECT email FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE email = @Email";

_command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.String);
```

And the list would return only entries matching the email. Empty if there isn't any matches.

Answer (score 0):

I think for less code and less actions; this code is better:

```
query = "SELECT email, isnull(count(email), 0) as NUM FROM RegisteredUsers GROUP BY email";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sql = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
sql.Fill(dt);

if (Int32.Parse(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()) > 0)
    // your email is more than one or repeated
```

And `dt[0][0]` returns the `email`.